# Writing an XBMC addon: how do I add a torrent to my home PC over LAN from RaspBMC?

Tags: networking, python, raspbmc, linux, kodi

I'm writing an XBMC addon using the xbmcswift2 framework. Building and navigating the GUI was fairly easy. I also wrote a scraper for vodo.net which will be displaying the available movies in the XBMC interface, so far so good. Here is where I need help:

When I select a movie in RaspBMC, I'd like to begin downloading the movie to a home PC running a BitTorrent application connected via LAN.

How do I communicate between RaspBMC and my home PC's BT application? Which torrent application will let me do this? Do I need an API? Transmission would be nice, but any (Linux) application will do. Googling has led me to mentions of something called "JSON-RPC". What is that and is it what I'm looking for?

If you can even point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I use 2 different approach.

1) Dropbox recipe:

- Both 2 nodes (PC and Raspberry) has Dropbox access.
- On Raspberry, downloaded .torrent files uploaded to a Dropbox shared folder (TORRENTS) via shell script.
- On PC, Transmission configured to watch and download the torrent files in the TORRENTS folder which shared via Dropbox.

So, when i download a .torrent file into Raspberry, Transmission find the torrent in folder then download starts automatically.

2) JSON-RPC recipe:

I use PERL script from http://bredsaal.dk/controlling-transmission-using-json-rpc-in-perl

This PERL script watches a folder for .torrent files, then request Transmission's RPC interface and download starts.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using BitTorrent, you may notice there is another great product by the same company which called `BitTorrent Sync`: https://www.getsync.com/, it can sync files from almost any devices.

In this case, you could create a folder shared with your PC and your raspberry pi, and let BitTorrent watch this folder and auto add tasks.

`SyncThing` is another option, it does the same thing with BitTorrent Sync, only it is open sourced and more light-weight.